# MySQL Connector/Node.js (xdevapi) - Expecting '.', '(' in Where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js

There's a table with two fields: `id1` and `id1` - and I need to `select` the rows where the values of both are not equal.

```
table
    .select('id1','id2')
    .where('id1 != id2')
    .execute(row => {
        console.log (row);
    });
```

For some reason, I get this error: (!)

```
id1 != id2
----^
Expecting '.', '(', got '!='
```

Why would it except '.' or '(' over there??

If i remove the `where` it works correctly (meaning - it simply returns all rows).

It looks like a kind of bug in the xdevapi package - but I couldn't fully find it (tried to debug the parser source and so on...)

Comment: Try use `<>` instead `!=`. Typically SQL uses `<>` as `not equal`.

Comment: Tried it. Same result.

Comment: How can be the same result if `!=` is not used? Try `.select(['id1', 'id2']).where('id1 <> id2')`.

Comment: I meant I'm getting the same error, with both using `!=` and `<>`. I know that `<>` is an alternative to `!=`. Anyway, I haven't solved it yet, but resorted to using NodeSession and executing "raw" sql, for now.